# Impresión huella digital desde un lector de huella

Tags: python

Tengo un software para el sector salud, y me piden un nuevo requerimiento, que le implemente un lector de huella y que imprima la huella del paciente en el certificado médico, puedo hacer eso con python? alguien me puede ayudar con este requerimiento, gracias

Comment: Usar google no es tan dificil, freddy: https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint  Intenta limitar stackoverflow solo para dudas de código.

Comment: Buenos días, perfecto lo tendré en cuenta, disculpen en todo caso y pues nada valida la observación la voy a tener muy en cuenta. Buen día